# Не получается установить тему Material Design

Tags: android, material-design

Написал приложение и т.к. натыкался на тему Material Design, решил попробовать перевести приложение на такой дизайн.

Переименовал строку в `style.xml`:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

На:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.NoActionBar">
```

Как приложение перестало запускаться, выдавая ошибку:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: dc.galos, PID: 23814
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{dc.galos/dc.galos.View.Authorization}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2650)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2720)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1567)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5917)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:888)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:749)
                   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:354)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:323)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:284)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
                      at dc.galos.View.Authorization.onCreate(Authorization.java:45)
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6286)
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1113)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2603)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2720) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1567) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5917) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:888) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:749)
```

Пишет, что мне нужно использовать тему `Theme.AppCompat`, но я хочу попробовать материальный дизайн... Как тут найти выход из положения?

Comment: с AppCompatActivity можно использовать только тему AppCompat. Для MaterialTheme используйте класс Activity и минимальное API проекта 21 и выше

Comment: Спасибо. Думал по поводу наследуемого класса активити, но на одном источнике прочитал, что надо использовать AppCompatActivity.
Попробую поменять на Activity

Comment: @ДмитрийЧубаров, Activity это либа в системе девайса. На каждом девайсе она своей версии. Отсюда куча проблем. А вот AppCompatActivity всегда той версии, которой вы указали. Засим все используют её - меньше проблем, лучше работает, больше информации, а возможности - те же. А тема - ничего вам не даст. В общем - не советую Activity использовать

Comment: вообще темы AppCompat и Material по сути одно и то же. Первая используется для поддержки темы Material на API <21.

Answer (score 1):

Для того чтоб установить тему ***Material Design*** используйте AppTheme из библиотеки поддержки  *Android Support Library* пример:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

Так как имена атрибутов из библиотеки поддержки не используют префикс 
**`android:`** Это используется только для атрибутов из фреймворка Android.

У вас даже в ошибке написано: Вы должны использовать тему Theme.AppCompat (или потомка) для вашей активити.